# react-native 0.64.2 firebase compilation error on setScreenName

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

Firebase compilation in error at `[FIRAnalytics setScreenName ...]` in `RNFirebaseAnalytics.m`

when updated to `react-native` **0.64.2** from **0.61**

`node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/analytics/RNFirebaseAnalytics.m`:20:19: error: no known class method for selector `'setScreenName:screenClass:'`

```
[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverriew];
```

The following build commands failed:
CompileC `/<PATH_TO_DERIVEDDATA>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseAnalytics.o` `/<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/analytics/RNFirebaseAnalytics.m` normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Comment: Also have this issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @user1356791 I have added the solution in answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Node Modules in the following file

```
/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/analytics/RNFirebaseAnalytics.m
```

Update the following line of code

```
[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverriew];
```

to

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView parameters: @{kFIRParameterScreenName: screenName}];
```

Comment: this leads to multiple other errors

Comment: @DjaferAbdelhadi such as? This resolved the image display issue for me.

Comment: I created a patch for this issue with: `yarn patch-package react-native-firebase`